# Solaris du --max-depth Equivalent

Tags: solaris, disk-space-utilization

I would like to do the Linux equivalent of `du --max-depth=1`  on Solaris.

I cannot find an equivalent in the man pages.  Any alternatives?

Comment: Does find have a max-depth option on Solaris? Can you pipe that out to an xargs du?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Won't this do it?

```
cd $TOP_LEVEL_DIR
du -s *
```

Comment: Yes, this works almost exactly like the Linux way, without a total count at the bottom, but I can use `du -s .` to get that one.  I modified to du -sh * for a more readable output.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could always install gnu fileutils and get the same functionality.  Blastwave would have pre-built packages for newer versions of Solaris.

Comment: Good solution, I just needed something quick and dirty for now, thanks.

Comment: Chances is that you have GNU du at /usr/gnu/bin/du.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work on Solaris?

```
du | egrep -v '.*/.*/.*'
```

Answer (score 0):

The du command included with OpenSolaris does support --max-depth!

Answer (score 0):

find ./ -type d -print -maxdepth 1|xargs du -hs